Angular navigation item: on first click navigate to page AND open dropdown?
I have Angular navigation item component:
<div(click)="handleToggleDropdown()">
  <a[routerLink]="route">{{ text }}</a>
</div>

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveOffcanvas } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'navigation-item',
  templateUrl: './navigation-item.component.html',
})
export class NavigationItemComponent {
  dropdownOpen = false;
  @Input() route?: string;
  @Input() text = '';
  @Input() hasDropdown = false;

  toggleDropdown() {
    this.dropdownOpen = !this.dropdownOpen;
  }
  handleToggleDropdown() {
    if (this.hasDropdown) {
      this.toggleDropdown();
    } else {
      this.activeOffcanvas.dismiss();
    }
  }
}

Now on first click Navigation item routes to page, and on second click opens dropdown.
Is it possible that on first click Navigation item both routes to page AND opens dropdown?
I tried like this:
  handleToggleDropdown() {
    if (this.hasDropdown) {
      if (!this.dropdownOpen) {
        this.router.navigate([this.route]);
      }
      this.toggleDropdown();
    } else {
      this.activeOffcanvas.dismiss();
    }
  }

but it doesn't work either

Maybe you can listen to the navigation events to do it :
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.pipe(tap((event) => {
     if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // After navigation ends, toggle the dropdown if it was supposed to open
          this.toggleDropdown();
      }
}), takeUntilDestroy()).subscribe();
  }

or
constructor(private router: Router) {
 this.router.events.pipe(
   filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd), 
   tap(() => this.toggleDropdown()), 
   takeUntilDestroy()
 ).subscribe();
}


Tim, not use tap, use filter and the subscribe function: this.router.events.pipe(filter(event:any=>event.instanceof NavigationEnd),takeUntilDestroy()).subscribe(_=>this.toggleDropdown())

Why dont use tap?? Yes we can replace the if by the filter operator too but we can still put nothing in subscribe if we want to keep logics with operators. I prefer using tap because we can easyly see that we have a side effect.

Personal opinion: subscribe is to execute one action, tap for kind of debug, store the response, etc (but of course it's perfect use as you indicate)
